# libcom_err.so.2: cannot open shared object file

Tags: centos, shared-library

I removed `libcom_err.so.2` library from `usr/lib64/` folder by mistake and `yum` command stopped working. I was wondering if there is any way to find this lib file and replace it in that folder since I do not have any backup from it. 
Is there any way to fix this issue? 
I am on CentOS 7.

P.S:
I think the files that I have to use are in package [libcom_err-1.42.9-16.el7.x86_64.rpm](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/libcom_err-1.42.9-16.el7.x86_64.rpm.html),
but do not know how I can extract those library files and copy them into that folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use:

```
rpm2cpio libcom_err-1.42.9-16.el7.x86_64.rpm | cpio -idmv
```

This will create installation structure in the current directory.

From there you can copy the missing file.

If those commands don't work, you might have to run that on a temporary machine then copy the file via SFTP.

Comment: But `yum` stopped working and also `sudo` does not work with the error like `libcom_err.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: He's already stated that `yum` doesn't work.

Comment: Pardon my blindness. Will update the answer :)

Comment: @DanilaVershinin thanks for the reply. how can I make sure that the rpm file matches with my linux?

Comment: I'm not sure how you can. But then again, if you use the file from the same CentOS version it should be pretty safe, because packages there are quite stable and ABI of libraries doesn't change between library package versions. Once you get yum working (after placing the file), you can ensure consistent version with the initial answer's command `yum reinstall libcom_err`

Comment: @DanilaVershinin also I think I can not make new connection to the machine anymore, I have no idea if that is because of that library or not, but currently I have an open ssh connection to the machine. but new connections breaks :(

Comment: Are you connected with a `root` account or a sudo account which can't sudo anymore?

Comment: @DanilaVershinin I am currently connected as a sudo account, shall I use su account? before that calling `sudo su` worked, now calling `su` does not accept the password which is wired. is `sudo su` diffrent than `su`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104491/discussion-between-danila-vershinin-and-majid-hojati).